# Chord diagram for relationship representation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, chord-diagram

I would like to leave here a bit of an abstract question.

I have a dataset, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("0002" ,"0022", "0025", "0025" ,"0209" ,"0029" ,"0218", "00128" ,"02039" ,"04039" , "00443" ,"00643", "00446", "00746" ,"09048" ,"00948"),
                 A = c("Yes" , "No" , "No" , "Yes"  ,"No" , "Yes"  , "No" , "Yes"  , "No" , "No" ,  "No"  ,"No" , "No" ,"Yes"  , "Yes"  , "Yes" ),
                 B = c("No"  , "No" , "No" , "No" , "Yes"  ,  "No" , "Yes"  , "Yes"    ,  "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "No" ,"Yes"  , "No" ,"No"  ,"Yes"  , "No"),
                 C = c( "Yes"  , "No" , "Yes"  , "No", "Yes"  , "Yes"   ,"Yes" ,  "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "Yes" , "No" , "Yes"  , "No" , "Yes"   ,"Yes" ), 
                 D = c( "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "No", "Yes"  , "No" , "Yes"   ,"Yes"  ,  "No" , "No" ,  "No" ,  "No" , "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "No" , "No"),
                 E = c("No" ,  "Yes"  ,"Yes"   ,"No" , "Yes"  ,"Yes"  , "Yes"  ,"Yes", "No"  ,"Yes"  , "No"  ,"Yes"  ,"Yes"  , "No" ,"No"  ,"Yes" ),
                 G= c("No" , "No" , "Yes"  , "No" , "No" , "No"  ,"Yes"  , "Yes"  , "Yes"  , "No" , "Yes"  , "No" ,  "No" , "No" ,"No" , "No"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And I am wondering if is possible to do some sort of CHORD DIAGRAM that represent the strength of interactions, for example, how strong is the appearance of A ==Yes and C==Yes together. Basically, I want to see which things happen together.

I know this is a bit abstract and maybe is not the best way of representing this. I am open to suggestions!

Thannks

Comment: My answer to "is it possible to xyz in R" questions is probably. It sounds like a network problem—I'd recommend starting by reading up on network analysis and diagrams, looking at examples of chord diagrams to show similar dynamics, then coming back here with a specific question if you get stuck. The `igraph` package, which you'll probably end up using, is pretty well documented. [This person](https://kateto.net/tutorials/) has extremely detailed tutorials as well

Comment: Your df is not correct Column E is length 17, the others are 16.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start:

What you need is:

1. the libraries `library(circlize) library(chorddiag) library(tidyverse)`
2. Some meaningful data in matrix from, here we do datawrangling to get the yes and no for group A-G and change to class martix `mat`
3. the so called adjacency list `adj_list`
4. Adding some color with `grid.col`
5. plot with `chordDiagram(mat, grid.col = grid.col)`

```
#install.packages("circlize")
#devtools::install_github("mattflor/chorddiag")

library(circlize)
library(chorddiag)
library(tidyverse)


mat <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -PatientID,
        names_to = "names", 
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    count(names, values) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = n) %>% 
    column_to_rownames(var="values") %>% 
    as.matrix()


adj_list = data.frame(from = rep(rownames(mat), times = ncol(mat)),
                to = rep(colnames(mat), each = nrow(mat)),
                value = as.vector(mat),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

grid.col = c(Yes = "green", No = "red", 
             A = "grey", B = "grey", C = "grey", D = "grey", E = "grey", G = "grey")
chordDiagram(mat, grid.col = grid.col)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! - this is actually a good approach if it would be possible to rather than link in the graph df$A for example with Yes or NO, my idea would be, for example link, df$A with df$B when both are Yes (this is an example). so the resulting circle graph would indicate how often things happen together. Makes sense? do you think this is possible?

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3206505.3206570 Not sure this might be useful